# Issue with page on mobile

Tags: html, css

i have an issue with my page showing on mobile which i cannot figure out. On mobile the page initially shows fine, but if moved to right a black line from top to bottom shows. Picture attached.
Any help will be appreaciated.

[image]

Comment: can you add some of your codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `<div class="container"></div>` in the "WHY CHOOSE US" section. When fixing it like this, it should work and the "black line", which is actually your background image, should be gone.

```
<!-- WHY CHOOSE US -->
<section id="frames" class="about-section all-space product-page">
    <div class="container"> <!-- <<< This is what you are missing -->
        <div class="row" style="overflow: hidden;">
         [...]
        </div>
    </div> <!-- <<< Close it properly -->
</section>
```